# Performance Gain From Excel 2007 to 2010/2013 for modern PC

Tags: microsoft-excel, performance, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

My work recently upgraded my department’s computers to shiny new spiffy i7 ssd 16GB RAM boxes. I spend most of my time in excel/access and the company still uses the 2007 versions of this software. Would I see large performance gains from switching to a more recent version of Excel?

One gain I know of is that upgrading will let us switch to a 64 bit version of Excel so we can utilize more RAM. Are there any others? I.T. told me that the changes are widely cosmetic between 2007 and 2013 so there is no point in updating. If I go back to challenge that decision I’d like to have a solid case.

Comment: I want to switch but IT is historically resistant to supporting any new software, much less two versions of the same software for different departments. I made this post to gain some info and build a case so when I go back to them I have solid arguments to justify the cost expenditure.

Answer (score 0):

Your I.T. have misinformed you. There are actually many improvements between the versions - e.g. Tables, Pivot Tables, Slicers, Excel Data Model/Power Pivot, Flash Fill, Quick Analysis and the best of all - the Power Query Add-In.

Here's a nice summary from Microsoft:

http://support.office.com/en-us/Article/What-s-new-in-Excel-2013-1cbc42cd-bfaf-43d7-9031-5688ef1392fd

Note those are just the enhancements from Excel 2010 to 2013.

Of course you or your I.T. could easily discover this yourselves - just look in the internet series of tubes for something like "excel 2013 whats new".